# using old port after chaging domain.xml

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-3, netbeans6.7

I am using Glassfish V3 which comes with netbeans only , as there are few servers running on my pc , i have changed the port **from 8080 to 8787** of glassfish v3 by altering domain.xml

```
<http-listener id="http-listener-1" port="8787" address="0.0.0.0" default-virtual-server="server" server-name="" />
<http-listener id="http-listener-2" port="8181" enabled="false" address="0.0.0.0" security-enabled="true" default-virtual-server="server" server-name="">
```

Now when i deploy the restful webservies over server or click on Test Restful Webservice in netbeans
i am getting a page in a browser which still uses the old port and even there is not webservice option get displayed on it the page is blank.  here is the screen shot

note: i tried restarting it may times but still using the old port

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Netbeans project node there must be a sub node like "Generated sources (rest-test)" or similar (I don't have Netbeans in english).

If you expand this node, there must be a file named *test-resbeans.html*. Open this file and check the following entry:

```
var baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/MyFirstWebService/||/resources";
```

The term MyFirstWebservice needs to be replaced by your services's name.

Change the port there if necessary.

Comment: But here everytime i need to change the port as an when i click in Test RestfulWebservices , do you have any permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

There was an open issue for something similar.  I fixed it a while back, but the change will be in NB 7.0.  I do not think anybody will backport the change into 6.7... but you never know.